# Higher kinded empty constraint

Tags: haskell, constraint-kinds

I want to have an empty constraint at a higher kind.

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Category k where
  type Obj k :: * -> Constraint
  id  :: Obj k a => a `k` a
  (.) :: (Obj k a, Obj k b, Obj k c) => b `k` c -> a `k` b -> a `k` c
```

Now I want to make an instance for functions such that it doesn't constrain the elements in any way. What do I give as an instance for `Obj`?

```
instance Category (->) where
  type Obj (->) = ?
  id    = \a -> a
  f . g = \a -> f (g a)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to give it an explicit additional argument in the class declaration.

```
class Category k where
  type Obj k a :: Constraint
```

Then it's easy to define the instances using the lower-kinded `()` empty constraint.

```
instance Category (->) where
  type Obj (->) a = ()
```

Comment: You can also make a type class `class Empty a` with no methods and a trivial `instance Empty a`.  It’s not quite what you asked for, but it should work.